# extracting specific but unknown values from a string in Java

Tags: java, mysql, string, substring

I am trying to extract values from a MySQL insert command in Java. The insert command is just a string as far as Java is concerned. it will be of the format

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES ("John Doe", "45", "engineer");
```

I need to pull the '45' out of that statement. I can't pinpoint its index because names and job titles will be different. I only need the age. Other than overly complex string manipulation which I could probably figure out in time, is there a more straight forward way of isolating those characters? I just cant seem to wrap my mind around how to do it and I am not very familiar with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the *specific* format of your message, then a regex like that should help:

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (".*?", "(.*?)", ".*?");
```

The read the first group of the result and you should get the age.

In regular expressions `(X)` defines a matching group that captures `X` (where `X` can be any regular expression). This means that *if* the entire regular expression matches, then you can easily find out the value within this matching group (using [`Matcher.group()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) in Java).

You can also have multiple matching groups in a single regex like this:

```
INSERT INTO employees VALUES ("(.*?)", "(.*?)", "(.*?)");
```

So your code could look like this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO employees VALUES (\"John Doe\", \"45\", \"engineer\");";
final Pattern patter = Pattern.compile("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (\"(.*?)\", \"(.*?)\", \"(.*?)\");");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sql);
if (matcher.matches()) {
  String name = matcher.group(1);
  String age = matcher.group(2);
  String job = matcher.group(3);
  // do stuff ...
}
```

Comment: can you explain this further? could this be used to extract each value? right now i only need to pull the ages out of this table but when I'm working with another table, could this be used again? like i said, i dont know much about regex.

Comment: I extended the answer, **but**: why do you try to parse an SQL statement in the first place? Only the DB should do that.

Comment: firstly, thanks for the help. this was my first time posting a question here. i send the statement straight to the DB but i need the values to be analyzed to determine if they should be added to other tables as well, or, for instance, moved when data is updated. Instead of manually going in and applying these changes. the ages were just an example, but your solution was perfect. im going to look more into regex for future projects.

Comment: @Michael: if such an interpretation of data is necessary, then you should **definitely** do that at a higher level (i.e. **before** the SQL statement is produced). Additionally, this leads me to be believe that you produce that SQL statement from user input, which should [definitely be avoided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind. These DBs are personally maintained and I am the only user. Just trying to make my life a little easier, and learn something along the way. Now, suppose I was inserting an entry into a different table or several different tables, how would I define the pattern? Are the first words (insert, into, employees, values) ignored and only the characters in the `(.*?)` read?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that name doesn't contain any " you can use regex `.*?".*?".*?"(\d+)".*` and group(1) gives you the age.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your insert command will insert into 3 columns only. What you can probably do split the string on the character comma (,) and then get the second element of the array, trim left and right white spaces and then extract the elements of it except the first and last character. That should fetch you the age. Writing a psuedocode for it:

```
String insertQuery="INSERT INTO employees VALUES (\"John Doe\", \"45\", \"engineer\")";
String splitQuery=insertQuery.split(",");
String age=splitQuery[1];
age=age.trim();
age=age.substring(1, age.length-2);
```

Comment: No solution if the name is `Doe, John`. You have to split at `",`

Answer (score 0):

How about String.split by ","?

```
final String insert = "INSERT INTO employees VALUES (\"John Doe\", \"45\", \"engineer\"); ";
System.out.println(insert.split(",")[1].trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is only one instance of a number in the string, the regular expression you need is very simple:

```
//Assuming that str contains your insert statement
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find()) System.out.println(m.group());
```